# Why when I take this class into my project don't find some namespaces\classes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

I am pretty new in C# (I came from Java) and I have the following problem: I am developing a new web application based on an old version of the same web application and I have to reuse an old class that is present in the old version of this webapplication.

The problem is that when I take this class into my new version I have some errors.

This is my class:

```
//using ITAttitude.Commons.Helpers;
//using ITAttitude.Commons.Logger;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting;

namespace PdfReport
{
    class ChartHelper
    {

        public static String GetPdfChart(int percentage)
        {
            if (percentage == 0)
            {
                return null;
            }

            int WIDTH = 130;
            int HEIGHT = 10;

            using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(WIDTH, HEIGHT))
            {
                using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                {
                    using (LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(new Rectangle(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT), Color.LightGreen, Color.Red, LinearGradientMode.Horizontal))
                    {
                        graphics.FillRectangle(brush, new Rectangle(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT));

                        using (Bitmap target = new Bitmap(WIDTH * percentage / 100, HEIGHT))
                        {
                            Rectangle cropped = new Rectangle(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

                            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(target))
                            {
                                g.DrawImage(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, cropped.Width, cropped.Height), cropped, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                                g.Save();

                                String filename = Path.GetTempFileName() + ".png";

                                target.Save(filename);

                                return filename;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And these are the obtained errors messages:

> Error 77  The type or namespace name 'UI' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\Develop\EarlyWarning\public\Implementazione\Ver2\PdfReport\ChartHelper.cs    10  18  PdfReport
>   Error 76  The type or namespace name 'Drawing2D' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'System.Drawing' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\Develop\EarlyWarning\public\Implementazione\Ver2\PdfReport\ChartHelper.cs    6   22  PdfReport
>   Error 78  Metadata file
>   'C:\Develop\EarlyWarning\public\Implementazione\Ver2\PdfReport\bin\Debug\PdfReport.dll'
>   could not be
>   found C:\Develop\EarlyWarning\public\Implementazione\Ver2\UnitTestProject\CSC UnitTestProject

It seems to me as it don't find some reference or some others classes. Why? What can I do to solve this issue?

Tnx

Comment: `I am pretty new in C# (I came from Java)` - Welcome to the Light Side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your project is missing references to `System.Web`,System.Drawing`and`System.Web.DataVisualization`.

Right click on project references and click Add References, select `System.Web`, `System.Drawing` and `System.Web.DataVisualization` under Assemblies/Framework.

Comment: mmm after it I still have the followings errors messages:

Error 76 The type or namespace name 'DataVisualization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.UI' (are you missing an assembly reference?) C:\Develop\EarlyWarning\public\Implementazione\Ver2\PdfReport\ChartHelper.cs 10 21 PdfReport
Error 77 Metadata file 'C:\Develop\EarlyWarning\public\Implementazione\Ver2\PdfReport\bin\Debug\PdfReport.dll' could not be found C:\Develop\EarlyWarning\public\Implementazione\Ver2\UnitTestProject\CSC UnitTestProject

Comment: @AndreaNobili, add reference to `System.Web.DataVisualization`

Comment: Ok...now the only error that remain is: Error 76 Metadata file 'C:\Develop\EarlyWarning\public\Implementazione\Ver2\PdfReport\bin\Debug\PdfReport.dll' could not be found C:\Develop\EarlyWarning\public\Implementazione\Ver2\UnitTestProject\CSC UnitTestProject

What is this? How can I solve?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the References folder in the project and select add reference. 
Search for System.Web.DataVisualization and check that and select Ok.
Try building it again, your error should go away.